# I can not resize my frameLayout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to be my camera screen only portrait mode and not allow landscape mode.
and also, I want to full screen in portait mode. 
 like google app camera

I refer the open source QUICK SNAP 
http://s.ppomppu.co.kr/?idno=developer_6022&target=https://github.com/lightbox/QuickSnap

first, I hold the portrait mode in java code at onCreate 
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

and, i could see portait mode but it was not the full size screen.
I tried to force the framelayout but it' doesn't work...
How can i handle the framelayout size or how can I make the full size? 
help me pls..... !!

here is my code and picture
http://blog.naver.com/sss8902/220118016613

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {     
    int frameWidth = getWidth();
    int frameHeight = getHeight();

    FrameLayout f = mFrame;
    int horizontalPadding = f.getPaddingLeft() + f.getPaddingRight(); //수평여백
    int verticalPadding = f.getPaddingBottom() + f.getPaddingTop();    // 수직여백. 
    int previewHeight = frameHeight - verticalPadding;
    int previewWidth = frameWidth - horizontalPadding;*/
    int previewHeight = frameHeight;
    int previewWidth = frameWidth;

    // resize frame and preview for aspect ratio
    if (previewWidth > previewHeight * mAspectRatio) {
        previewWidth = (int) (previewHeight * mAspectRatio + .5);
    } else {
        previewHeight = (int) (previewWidth / mAspectRatio + .5);
    }*/

    frameWidth = previewWidth + horizontalPadding;
    frameHeight = previewHeight + verticalPadding;

    int hSpace = ((r - l) - frameWidth) / 2;
    int vSpace = ((b - t) - frameHeight) / 2;
    mFrame.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(frameWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(frameHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    mFrame.layout(l + hSpace, t + vSpace, r - hSpace, b - vSpace);
    if (mSizeListener != null) {
        mSizeListener.onSizeChanged();
    }
}
```